# Button inside RecycleView doesn't react at click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a `RecycleView` component inside `LinearLayout` with some others components too. The issue is whenever I click at the element at `RecycleView` component it should create a `TAG` in console, but it doesn't. I have added `onClickListiner` but it doesn't react at all.

Below there is a piece of code how I create a `RecycleView` inside the `Activity` class and the `Adapter`.

The activity class:

```
  mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(washLocations, this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

The Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<WashLocation> washLocations;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyAdapter(List<WashLocation> washLocations, Context context) {
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.washLocations = washLocations;
        }

        @Override
        public MyAdapter.ViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            // Inflate the custom layout
            View contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_recycleview, parent, false);

            // Return a new holder instance
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(context, contactView);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            // Get the data model based on position
            WashLocation w = washLocations.get(position);
            String info = w.getWashName();

            // Set item views based on your views and data model
            TextView textView = holder.info;
            textView.setText(info);

            Integer fav = w.getFav();
            Boolean favorite = fav == 1 ? true : false;
            Button addToFav = holder.favorite;
            addToFav.setText(favorite == true ? "Usuń z ulubionych" : "Dodaj do ulubionych");
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return washLocations.size();
        }


        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            private Context context;
            public TextView info;
            public Button favorite;

            public ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                this.context = context;
                info = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                favorite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToFav);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition(); // gets item position
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) { // Check if an item was deleted, but the user clicked it before the UI removed it
                    // We can access the data within the views
                    Toast.makeText(context, info.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("myTag", "This is my message");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the `onBindViewHolder` to set the `Listener` because in this method we have the position. Try to change your method to this:

@Override

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Get the data model based on position
   final WashLocation w = washLocations.get(position);
   final String info = w.getWashName();

    // Set item views based on your views and data model
    TextView textView = holder.info;
    textView.setText(info);

    Integer fav = w.getFav();
    Boolean favorite = fav == 1 ? true : false;
    Button addToFav = holder.favorite;
    addToFav.setText(favorite == true ? "Usuń z ulubionych" : "Dodaj do ulubionych");
  holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view){
        //Here you have all the data that you want
        //you can use w variable : w.getWashName();
       }

  });
}
```

To add 2 different listener for each button:

```
holder.yourButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view){
       //Click for button 1
       }

  });
}

holder.yourButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       @Override
       public void onClick(View view){
       //Click for button 2
       }

  });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add two diffrent `onClickListener` to diffrent buttons in one row of `RecycleView`?

Comment: Thank you very much! :) One more thing - when I click at the button, is there a posibility to get the object from list on which the listener was activated?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the onClickListener on the ViewGroup for the element. You should be putting it on the button.

Try using this:

```
public ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.context = context;
    info = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    favorite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToFav);
    favorite.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your viewholder code like this,

```
public ViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                this.context = context;
                info = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                favorite = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToFav);
                favorite2 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToFav2);
                favorite.setOnClickListener(this);
                favorite2.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view){
            switch(view.getId()) {
                 case R.id.addToFav :
                      // onclick of button 1
                      break;
                 case R.id.addToFav2 :
                      // onclick of button 1
                      break;
            }
       }
```

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: @bielas check the smart way handling multiple button click in recyclerview.